# eclipse + cdt + mingw + windows error "undefined reference to `WinMain@16'" on build

Tags: windows, eclipse, mingw, eclipse-cdt

I installed eclipse, cdt and mingw on my windows XP machine. added `C:\MinGW\bin` to my PATH.

Created a new c++ project, with one file in it, test.c. the code in it:

```
int main(){
   int i=1;
}
```

Trying to build, I get the error:
`/mingw/lib/libmingw32.a(main.o):main.c:(.text+0xd2): undefined reference to 'WinMain@16'`

Notice it's not complaining about `test.c` but rather about some `main.c` in one of mingw's libs.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have the command line which is being used to invoke compiler available? Your problem appears to be one of linking, not compilation. (Perhaps you're missing a link to `libmsvcrt.a`)

Comment: @Mark - thanks, I failed to notice that compile and linkage commands  are trying to compile a different file than the one that contains the main

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, the solution was really weird, but I guess it would make sense to someone more proficient with CDT than me - 
My main() was inside a .c file. When I changed the suffix to be .cpp, it worked like a charm.

Comment: Perhaps since you created a "C++ Project" CDT did not consider the .c file part of it.

Comment: The exact opposite happened to me: my main() was inside a .cpp file and the project was a "C Project", hence CDT did not consider the .cpp file.

Answer (score 3):

You need to save the `.c` file first.

Answer (score 0):

main.o from libmingw32.a should not be searched by the linker because the undefined symbol _main from crt2.o is (should be) satisfied by the "int main()" which you wrote.

Please copy & paste the gcc command lines that cdt is executing.